# Sending mail with php: Header gets broken

Tags: php, email, header

I use the following code to send a mail:

```
$recipient="mymail@example.com";
$body="<html><body>This is magic</body></html>";
$subject="hi folks!";
$thisMail="sender@example.com";
$replyHeader = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nFrom: ".$thisMail. "\r\nReply-To: ".$thisMail."\r\n";
mail($sender, "Re:".$subject, $body, $replyHeader);
```

The mail is sent, but when I open it in a client mailer, the header seems to be broken. Everything after the first New Line (\r\n) is shown in the mail. Also some other header-contents are displayed. So the **visible body** of the mail looks like this in a mail client:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
From: sender@example.com
Reply-To: sender@example.com
Envelope-To: mymail@example.com
X-UI-Filterresults [... lots of stuff]

<html><body>This is magic</body></html>
```

What is going wrong there?

One (out of many) examples that show it "should" work that way: http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: `What is going wrong there?` - my generic answer is: you're building an email "blob" with just string concatenation. well _there's_ your problem.  There are better solutions, e.g. http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: You don't want to tell my I would need to use an external library to send a simple mail with php? It "should" work the way I did it according to multiple sources in the web.

Comment: BTW: Anyone can tell why this is downvoted? This is a valid question IMHO...

Comment: did it work when you tried it the way css tricks shows (concatenating the strings separately rather then one string?) was there any difference in the online files and the download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than relying on the `mail` function there are some really great libraries out there that handle headers, attachments, content and sending for you.

One of them - which is used by Laravel and other frameworks - is [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), you should check it out.

They have some good [documentation on setting headers](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/headers.html) too!

Honestly, you'll gain a lot from making use of the library and not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: Thanks for your answer. But do I really need a library for a really simple E-Mail? I do not want any fancy stuff, "just" a simple mail with html. There are (at least) a few hundred websites that suggest doing it just the way I did. (including the official documentation)

Comment: It's not a simple email when you start adding headers etc. You may as well develop something properly the first time, so that if you need to extend it later and send attachments, then you're in a position to do so.

Comment: "But do I really need a library for a really simple E-Mail?" - Yes. EMail is a more or less solved problem that only bites back if and when you don't use the proper tools. mail() + string-concat are not the proper tools. Search only on stackoverflow: it's full of shipwrack scripts like yours (no offense). It looks easy but in practice isn't ...unless you use the proper tools.

Comment: Ok. I will try that. It always feels a bit like surrendering to use external tools for something that seems simple, but I will give it a try this time :) Thanks

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Like @VolkerK said, sending e-mail is done really well already and you can save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: `external tools` - you wrote the mail() function? Or the mta behind it? In the end it's all external tools; we all stand on the shoulder of giants; fight the "not invented here" syndrome ;-)